# Prove that if the complex function $|f(z)|^2$ is constant in $D$ and $f(z)$ is analytic in $D$, then $f(z)$ is constant in $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing

My proof:

Let $|f(z)|^2 = M$ for $z\in D$.

Then $f(z) = \pm\sqrt{M}$ (not sure about this step, are there only two values for the square root of a complex number> No right? Could be more. But I don't think it would change the essence of the proof)

But $f(z)$ is analytic in $D$ so it cannot be the case that $f(z_1) = \sqrt{M}$ and $f(z_2) = -\sqrt{M}$ for $z_1,z_2\in D, z_1 \neq z_2$.

So $f(z)$ is constant in $D$

---

Does this proof make sense? How do I account for the non-principal values of the square roots of $M$?

Comment: "Then $f(z) = \pm\sqrt{M}$" this is false, for example if $f(z) = i$, then $|f(z)|^2 = 1$, but $f(z) \neq \pm 1$.

Comment: Hint: Maximum Modulus Principle

Comment: Have you tried using the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I have such a proof already. I'm trying something different.

Comment: What you're trying can't work, @Patterns. There's a whole circle of complex numbers with a given modulus.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you say that $f(z)=\pm e^{\frac{1}{2}log(M)}$?

Comment: No. Consider all points $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in\Bbb R$. They all have modulus $1$. Can you write them in your way? As you'll learn later, presumably, complex logarithms involve angles and not just modulus. And there is not always a well-defined complex logarithm.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. So is there a way to get $f(z) = ...$ in terms of $M$? BTW I was using the complex logarithm there.

Comment: No, only in the form $f(z) = \sqrt M e^{i\theta(z)}$ for some (quite possibly discontinuous) function $\theta(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mid f(z)\mid^2= M$ then the image of $f$ is contained in a circle. By the open mapping theorem, $f$ is constant.

Comment: I suspect you're using a cannon to kill a fly. Typically, this is assigned as an exercise very early on in a complex variables course.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already seen the maximum modulus principle and/or the open mapping theorem, the problem becomes trivial. Here's a proof using just the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

Write $f$ as a function of two real variables: $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. We are given $u(x,y)^2+v(x,y)^2 \equiv M$. Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ gives $2uu_x+2vv_x=0$, and doing the same for $y$ gives $2uu_y+2vv_y=0$. Rewrite these two equations as a single matrix equation, and take the determinant of the matrix, using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. You should get $u_x^2+u_y^2$. so, whenever $f(x,y) \neq 0$ (hence by continuity $f$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of $(x,y)$), you can deduce that the matrix is singular, hence $u_x^2+u_y^2=0$, but then all first order partials of $u$ and $v$ must be zero, hence $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of every $z$ with $f(z) \neq 0$. Of course, $f$ is also constantly zero on the complement of this set. Now since $f$ is continuous, you can see that $f$ is constant using a connectedness argument.